# Algorithm, that removes duplicates from array doesn't work

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an char array, that has some duplicate values:

```
A B C D E F E A
```

And this is my algorithm to remove the duplicate values:

```
char array[20] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'A'};
int length = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j])
            {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                length--;
            }
        }
    }

EXPECTED OUTPUT: A B C D E F
OUTPUT: A B C D E F A
```

I have tried to run this algorithm on papers, it seems okay when I do this in writing, however it doesn't work in my application.

Comment: I'm guessing `counter` is the result length.

Comment: Sorry I haven't rewritten it when I was posting here. It should be length instead of counter.

Comment: Your "duplicate removal" step reliably creates a new duplicate.  Instead of `a[j] == a[i]` you now have `a[j] == a[j+1]`.  Always

Comment: Learn about single stepping in a debugger, perhaps.  Beats "tried to run on paper" every time.

Comment: What you posted is not an algorithm, it's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another for loop inside the if statement
check the code below:

```
char array[20] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'A'};
```

int length = 8;

```
for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++){

        for(int j = i+1; j <= length; j++){

                if(array[j] == array[i]){

                            for(int x = j+1; x <=length; x++){

                                    array[j]=array[x];

                                    }
                            length--;
                            }

                }

        }

for(int z = 0; z <= length; z++){
      cout << array[z] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`j < length` allows `[j + 1]` to go beyond length

As elements are moved, `length` is no longer the length of valid data.  `counter` might be, but you don't show the code for how it is initialized.

Question edited to use `length--` instead of `counter--` but the error is in advancing `j` all the way to the end in the inner loop which contains a `j + 1`.  There is also no need to extend take `i` all the way to `length` in the outer loop since the inner loop sets jet to `i + 1`

Comment: So in first loop is set i < length - 1, so that last element wouldn't be checked and I can check the last element in other array. However the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior.

In the first iteration of the outer loop (i = 0) and the last iteration of the inner loop (j = 7, where length = 8), `array[i] == array[j]` is true because both are 'A'. But then you access `array[j+1]`, which is outside the bounds.

Then, when i = 4 and j = 6, you copy the value at 7 (which is now overwritten with garbage, but apparently happens to be 'A' in your case) to index 6, giving the wrong result you see.

You need to make the copying of the element conditional on `j < (length - 1)` to avoid the UB. Then you should get the right result in this instance at least.

Comment: Question edit reveals: There is extra space after the real data, containing NULs.

Comment: I have changed j < length to j < (length - 1), the output is A B C D E F A

Comment: @EvaldasB Well, that's wrong too. You need to check that last element, but you shouldn't copy from beyond it.

Answer (score 1):

Though I know it doesn't directly solve the question, here is the better-code alternative by which you can avoid such problems (requires C++11 for the vector initialization):

```
std::vector<char> in{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'A'};
std::vector<char> out;

std::sort (in.begin(),in.end());

std::unique_copy(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
```

If you do not need a copy, you can also use `std::unique` instead of `std::unique_copy`.

Comment: `std::unique_copy` removes only consecutive duplicates

Comment: THanks for the comment. So one has to do a sort in advance.

Comment: You have to sort `in`, not `out` :)

Answer (score 0):

It only works from i=0 through 3.

When i=4, array[4] = 'E', array[j] = 'F', it passes. j++
When i=4, array[4] = 'E', array[j] = 'E', array[j] is set to array[j+1], which is 'A'.

Shifting works fine but the loop for i may be the whole length of the array instead of changed length, since it stops when i=5.